# Cascade type Persist save only ID for child entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have such model :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class PersistentTest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_report_id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<PersistentReport> reports;

public PersistentTest(List<Report> reports) {
        this.reports = reports.stream().map(PersistentReport::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I have JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface JpaTestRepository extends JpaRepository<PersistentTest, Long> {}
```

I have such save operation:

```
public void add(List<Report> reports) {
    PersistentTest test = new PersistentTest(reports);
    repository.save(report);
}
```

After calling save(), new entity "Test" is saved, entities "Report" also saved.
But all fields except "id" in all "Report" entities are "null".

Adding Cascade type Merge fixes the problem, but adding Persist without Merge also should do this, is not it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my big fault.
I am not persisting new Test, but updating it. Whats why PERSIST only not works.